# tensorflow: Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

When i run my program i see this error:
[image]

I have CUDA 11 and there is not such dll file in bin folder:

[image]

I use:

Python 3.8.7

CUDA 11.0

tensorflow 2.4.1

On this page there is information https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu
tensorflow-2.4.0    Python 3.6-3.8  CUDA  11.0
that that versions are correct.
Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? What should I download or reinstall?

Comment: you have to install cuDNN (version 8, as indicated on the tensorflow page you linked).  It is not part of the CUDA toolkit, it is a separate install.

Comment: Thanks, it work :) Now i have a different error "CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version", i will try to fix it.

Comment: update to the latest driver for your GPU

Comment: @Cierniostwor, Ideally TF 2.4 with CUDA 11 and cuDNN 8.0 combination should work. After updating driver if you are still facing any issues, simple workaround is first uninstall tensorflow and install freshly. It will resolve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) as well (v8 specifically).